# Как подгружать и закрывать страницы?

Tags: ajax, html, javascript

Добрый день. Имеется сайт в разработке http://plast-pak.esy.es/ пока что на стадии верстки.

На главной очень специфичная карусель, которая почему то не дает совершенно обращаться через js к своим элементам. Почему - так и не разобрался... но суть не в этом. Нашел способ как вызвать ajax'ом страницу с подробной информацией текущего элемента.

```
<button onclick="clickAlert();" class="clickDown">Подробнее</button>

<script>
function clickAlert() {
        $(this).click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                url: 'item-1.html',
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#projectInformation').html(response).slideDown('fast');
                }
            });
            $('.front-page > #main_wrap').slideUp(3000);
            $('.front-page > #menuBar').slideUp(3000);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Вызывается страница с подробностями. На ней есть также кнопка которая закрывает эту новость и возвращает обратный вид главной.

```
<button onclick="clickAbort();" class="clickUp">Вернуться на главную</button>

<script>
    function clickAbort() {
        $(this).click(function(){
            $('.front-page > #main_wrap').slideDown(3000);
            $('.front-page > #menuBar').slideDown(3000);
            $('#projectInformation .full-node').remove();
        });
    }
    </script>
```

В итоге все работает так, как работает. Все ужасно и очень некорректно. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, почему это все так работает. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, поставьте вопрос конкретнее. Два раза прочитал Ваш вопрос и так не смог понять, что же Вам не понятно. А если не понятно всё, то тут никто Вам не разжует jquery